# How can I get a Jenkins (formerly known as Hudson) plugin Created?

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I am extremely busy right now. So, I cannot build plugins at this moment.

How can I put in a request for a Jenkins plugin to be created? I want a Jasmine plugin for Jenkins created.

I do not see the answer at the [Jenkins Plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extend+Jenkins).

Again, I wish I had time to create one. However, I barely have time to write this question! :)

Thank you!

Comment: Bear in mind, open source works on the concept of *scratching an itch*. If you have an itch, *you* will either need to do the work or fund it in some way. Your only other option is to hope somebody else has the same itch.

Comment: Yes, thank you Daniel. I am bearing that in mind. If it doesn't happen in the near future then so be it. I have to choose my ROI carefully these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try posting on the jenkins mailing list. There also is a list with plugin ideas somewhere in the Jenkins Wiki, however, it is outdated, and hard to find, so I would not bother much with it. Best option should be the mailing list, lots of plugin developers roam around there.

Comment: It was a great suggestion. I tried the email list and have not received a response yet.

Comment: I went ahead and awarded this answer as the accepted answer since it's a great answer and I know of no other.